# Excel pivot table: How to transpose multiple value in column to a column labels

Tags: excel, row, pivot-table

Here's the pivot table I have in excel:
I have a list of website with their emails address.
Sometime you have one email per website, sometime you have 3 emails per website.
I want to transpose the multiple emails I have for one website that are in column Email 1 into multiple field such as Email 1, Email 2, Email 3 for EACH corresponding websites.

Here's an example of my pivot table:

**URL      |     Email **

site.com     | Email 1

```
       |Email 2
```

site2.com | Email 1

site3.com | Email 1

```
       |Email 2

       |Email 3
```

site4.com   | Email 1

I want to turn it into:

**URL      |    Email   | Email 2| Email 3**

site.com  | Email 1| Email 2

site2.com | Email 1

site3.com | Email 1| Email 2| Email 3

site4.com   | Email 1

Sorry about the format.
So the idea is simple, I just need to transpose the multiple emails I have for a website into columns.
but when I put the email field into Column Label, it takes every emails and instead of 3 emails columns labels (since I have no more than 3 emails per website) I have 7 column labels.

Any idea of who to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish Excel's pivot tables had better functionality for this, but I'm not aware of any way to get it directly.

That said, you can achieve this with some formulas:

1) Add a COUNT and LOOKUP column to your data

[image: SCreenshot of additional formulas]

2) Make a pivot table to get a unique list of URLS

3) Use `IFERROR` combined with `VLOOKUP` to fill in your transposed table:

[image: Screenshot of lookups]

Here is a [sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10791482/SO_PivotTranspose.xlsx) showing how it all comes together.

Comment: Thanks so much Tim, that does it for me!!This is saving me a huge ammount of time...kudo to you!!That's gonna be much easier to import everything into a dB.

Comment: Glad it helped.  If you can mark the answer as accepted it will help other people who might come across the same question.